# how to pass <std::function<void(int)>> paramater in c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, std-function

i'm trying to perform a thread pool design pattern in c++, but i'm stuck on passing a task  function parameter in order to push it inside a list 
here is my code

```
  std::list<std::function<void(int)>> work_queue;
```

my push function

```
 void pushTask(std::function<void(int)> func , int a) 
{ 
std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(wq_mutex);
work_queue.push_back(std::function<void(int)>(func),a));
 }
```

and here my main function with the task functin

```
void calcul(int a){
std::cout << a << "\n";
}

int main(){
ThreadPool th(10);
th.pushTask(std::bind(&calcule,4));
return 0;
```

}

i getting an error in this line

```
   work_queue.push_back(std::function<void(int)>(func),a));
```

can anyone identify the issue please ?

Comment: Avoid using that sort of cast, it should be `work_queue.push_back(func, a);`. In your example you have mismatched parentheses. If you are still having trouble then post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: When the compiler gives you an error, it's important to read it carefully.  If you don't understand it and want to post a whole Stack Overflow question about it, the minimum you should do is include the error message with your code.

Comment: whats the error say? I think I count an extra `)`, is that the problem?

Comment: i changed the error line to  work_queue.push_back(func,a); and i'm still getting the error: no matching function  error

Comment: Note that the result of `std::bind(&calcule,4)`is not implicitly convertible to `std::function<void(int)>` since you explicitly bind the parameter `4` -- its \`effective' type is `std::function<void()>`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the second argument to `pushTask`?  You are not invoking it with 2 arguments, and you have already bound an argument to `func`.

Comment: @G.M. so how should i modify my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You doing that wrong.

```
std::list<std::function<void()>> work_queue; // you do not need int here

void pushTask(std::function<void()> func) // so here it is also obsolete
{ 
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(wq_mutex);
    work_queue.push_back(std::move(func));
}

// now this will be ok
th.pushTask(std::bind(&calcule,4));
// but since this is C++11 lambda is preferred 
th.pushTask([]() { calcule(4); } );
```

Comment: it works ,thanks , what's the std::move role please ?

Comment: read about move schematics in C++11.

Comment: Anyway since it looks like you are a newbie I recommend you to avoid use of threads until you greatly improve your skills.
I know threads looks very fancy and fashionable, but they are hard to master. Biggest issue use of threads are not deterministic. So you can think that created nice pice of software since it works on your machine, but there is bug which will happen always on some machine.